# How long of a wire and how big of a load can I have for SPI bus?

Tags: spi, i2c, capacitance, transmission-line

I have a system where I will connect up to 128 identical magnometer ICs up to an FPGA. I am trying to decide between SPI and I2C for comms. If I use SPI the setup will require 128 + 3 wires IF all sensors are on the same bus.

How do I decide/calculate if this is feasible and the sensors and wire won't load the circuit with too much capacitance or resistance?

The sensors will be distributed across several circuit boards so most of the wire length will be connecting sensor boards to each other.

I guess a general answer would be nice but just in case I am using these sensors and FPGA.

- https://embeddedmicro.com/tutorials/mojo/
- http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00057547.pdf

EDIT: I appreciate any helpful advice on changing the system but what I'm looking for is how to calculate how many wires and sensors I can add before the capacitance is too great.

Comment: Why not use a multiplexer and differential signaling?

Comment: What data rate are you planning to use? Can it operate in daisy chain mode?

Comment: I haven't decided the data rate but 1Mhz or so would be ideal. Down to 200kHz might be doable. Daisy chaining would make the system too slow

Comment: Please tell me how would a multiplexer and differential signaling work? The sensors take single-ended signals.

Comment: You have a driver on one side, and a receiver on the other. Or just on one side if the FPGA can generate/process a differential signal.

Comment: Oh I see. I guess I should explain my setup more. The sensors will be distributed across several circuit boards so most of the wire length will be connecting sensor boards to each other.

Comment: Given the low(ish) data rate, and multiple sensors on each board(?), why not aggregate the sensors on each board into a single high-speed data stream (with a small local FPGA perhaps), then ship the high-speed streams back on a more appropriate comms protocol like 8b10b over LVDS.

Comment: Because that would be really expensive. The separate boards have nothing on them except 2 magnetometers and some capacitors.

Comment: 1Mbps is SPI territory.   Up to 400kbps is I2C territory  (although this budget would include the I2C address byte).  Here's something that nobody has mentioned yet: the LSM303D can only have four (4) unique I2C slave addresses.  If you want to use I2C bus, you would have to do something along the lines of multiplexing the bus.

Comment: It's actually only 2 unique addresses per bus. Hence, why I'm asking about SPI not I2C. I love how everyone is solving the problems I'm not asking about :)

Comment: Nobody in their right mind would design a system with 128+3 interconnecting wires. Too expensive and error prone. That is why you are getting such answers. Daisy chaining is the way to go if you must use SPI. With daisy chaining you can more easily add buffering to solve the drive strength problem and reach higher speeds. But importantly: Using SPI like this will be a EMC nightmare. There is no way you will be able to CE or FCC certify this, and it might not be particularly reliable

Answer (score 1):

To answer your main question: No, SPI TTL or CMOS signals can not reliably drive 128 loads via off-board cables.
There is no easy calculation you can do to show this. It has to do with both loading, reflections and ground references. You can simulate the propertis of such a system, but it is a complicated waste of time.

What might work reasonably well is to use RS422 drivers and receivers specified for as many loads as you need. You also need to terminate each differential pair at the furthest end.
If you have multiple SPI slaves per board, then they can share RS422 receivers.
You also probably want to at least partially daisy chain your SPI slaves. For example, all slaves on a single board could form a chain. It will greatly reduce your cabling.

This way you will have differential signaling in your cables, which can handle more loads and is a way more reliable signaling scheme in cables.
It does however double you number of wires..

But a disclaimer is in order: No one in their right mind would design a system like this with 128+3 signaling lanes.

Comment: Often the best solution to a problem like this is a moderate number of identical boards each handling a moderate number of sensors and then fanning in some concise representation of the results.  And it's typically cheaper even in a prototype run to design and build multiple copies of something of moderate size than one copy of something big.  Even if a "master" is needed it may be possible to have that be a configuration or bitstream variant of the same board.  FWIW the question is almost six years old.